# Display Currency symbols in a Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, currency

I am retrieving data from sharepoint library in a table. For currency column, i set it as indian currency. And i set spfield.dataformatstring as {0:c}. It is by default showing $ symbol instead of indian currency symbol.

How can i show the actual currency symbol?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution. Here is the code snippet:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(spfield.SchemaXml));
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode node = doc.ReadNode(reader);
string curSymbol = "";
if (node.Attributes["LCID"] != null)
{
    string lcidValue = node.Attributes["LCID"].Value;
    CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo( Convert.ToInt32(lcidValue));
    curSymbol = ci.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;                
}
field.HtmlEncode = false;
field.DataFormatString = curSymbol + " {0:#,###.##}";
```

It is working fine without do anything in web.config.

Comment: Given that you can create a CultureInfo object directly from it's LCID (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/205h6kwc.aspx) why go to all that trouble? Why not just create the CI directly from the LCID rather than looping through all available cultures trying to find a match?

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass in the [correct culture information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#CFormatString) to the formatter, however I'm unsure if you can do that directly within the composite formatting, however you could do something like:

```
string.Format("The total amount is: {0}", total.ToString("c2",
                                          CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("in-IN"));
```

The other option is to ensure that you've set the culture of your page or site as a whole correctly - clearly the server thinks it's serving pages up by default in the en-US culture.

This can usually be done site wide in the web.config, using the `<globalization uiCulture="in" culture="in-IN" />` element, or at the page level in the page directive `<%@ Page UICulture="in" Culture="in-IN" %>`.

That being said, SharePoint adds some additional complexity into the mix, requiring the site to have been created with the required language, and therefore to have the right language packs installed on top of it.

Comment: It wont work for my scenario. Because i am adding columns dynamically. So I cant get the col names.

Comment: @Ramesh.kbvr Then you're pretty much stuck with setting the culture of the entire page or even site correctly. Another option that might be available is to process the currency conversion elsewhere before the data is bound to the control - is that a possibility?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the correct [culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28VS.71%29.aspx).